# Can't Login To Server 08 R2 server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, login

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 box running Hyper-V hosting VM's.  The server is a Dell M610 Blade server.  The VM's are performing normally.

However, I cannot RDP into the server.  I get prompted for username and password, then after I hit enter I am returned to the RDP connection screen.

I tried to connect Event Viewer remotely and got an Access Denied error.

I went to the chassis console and used the iDRAC gui to access the server.  However, when I send the Ctrl-Alt-Del keystrokes, all I get on the screen is a Cancel button, no boxes for logging in with user name and password.

Anyone have any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Can you remotely look at the event logs?

Comment: No cannot connect with Event Viewer from Windows 7 machine, cannot access logs via PowerShell either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was going on but a reboot fixed the issue.  I tried using an older version of the RDP client with no success.

Answer (score 2):

try rdpclient version 5. you need to hack around a bit to get it running in parallel with xpsp2+ clients which have version 6 "build-in"
it helped me to get in to windows 2008R2, later on i restarted DC and I could magically log on to every srv. windows2003 was behaving normally.